# Import statement withing a function, wishful thinking?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hi there I was wondering if it's possible to do imports inside a for loop. When trying to execute this code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
function importFiles(x) {
  fs.readdir(x, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
        var doc = file
        var char = /.+(?=\.\w+)/.exec(file);
        import {doc} from str(x + char);
    });
  })
}
importFiles('../public/img/');
```

I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`. Obviously this might be wishful thinking (since I cannot find any documentation on this) but I was wondering if I could somehow decide on how much to import within a  function.

Comment: `import`, by rule, has to be at the top of your script. Inside of a function, you have to use the `require` syntax.

Comment: `require({char})(str(x + doc));`  states that path must be a string. Is there a proper way to word this?

Comment: Take a look at the proposed [import()](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) syntax - it allows for this kind of implementation